# Combine two dictionaries with preference to one of them -

Tags: python, dictionary, grouping

I have two dictionaries

**One:**

```
default = {"val1": 10, "val2": 20, "val3": 30, "val4": 40}
```

**Two:**

```
parsed = {"val1": 60, "val2": 50}
```

Now, I want to combine these two dictionaries in such a way that values for the keys present in both the dictionaries are taken from the `parsed` dictionary and for rest of the keys in `default` and their values are put in to the new dictionary.

For the above given dictionary the newly created dictionary would be,

```
updated = {"val1": 60, "val2": 50, "val3": 30, "val4": 40}
```

The obvious way to code up this would be to loop through the keys in `default` and check if that is present in `parsed` and put then into a new list `updated`, and in the else clause of the same check we can use values from `default`.

I am not sure if this is a pythonic way to do it or a much cleaner method. Could someone help on this?

Comment: `updated = {**default, **parsed}`, starting from python 3.9 ([PEP 0584](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/)) you can use also `updated = default | parsed`

Comment: Nope. My question is on giving preference to a dictionary over another in a combine expression.

Comment: Not sure why the comment was deleted. The duplicate target *does* answer the question. See, for example, the accepted answer: "The desired result is to get a new dictionary (z) with the values merged, and the *second dictionary's values overwriting those from the first.*"  The answers here don't add anything new and just repeat the solutions given in the duplicate target.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create a new dict with `{**dict1,**dict2}` where `dict2` is the one that should have priority in terms of values

```
>>> updated = {**default, **parsed}
>>> updated
{'val1': 60, 'val2': 50, 'val3': 30, 'val4': 40}
```

Answer (score 10):

First, create a copy of the `dict` with values you want to keep using the [`dict.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy) method Then, use the [`dict.update()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/update.html#syntax) method to update the other `dict` into the create `dict` copy:

```
default = {"val1": 10, "val2": 20, "val3": 30, "val4": 40}
parsed = {"val1": 60, "val2": 50}

updated = default.copy()
updated.update(parsed)

print(updated)
```

Output:

```
{'val1': 60, 'val2': 50, 'val3': 30, 'val4': 40}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can also:

```
updated = {**default, **parsed}
```

Outputs:

```
{'val1': 60, 'val2': 50, 'val3': 30, 'val4': 40}
```